# How to avoid invoking the same module every time when I have to call a function of that module in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, performance, blocks

When there is a need **to call a function inside a module**, some of you say- **it is good to use `module_invoke()` inside the template pages to call the function(it looks great-since I can pass arguments too).**

Using Drupal 7. So for the first time, it is okay. Even for the second time, it makes a bit extra effort in the code, but somehow I can manage it.

Now it is invoking again and again, the same module. Say if the module is `block`, and the function is `hook_block_view()`- I doubt, **it could affect the Drupal site performance(the time for loading the page contents)**, what do you think?
Is there a solution for this problem?

```
<?php
  $header_block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', '2');
  print drupal_render($header_block);
  $news_block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', '3');
  print drupal_render($news_block);
  ...
  ...
  $footer_block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', '12');
  print drupal_render($footer_block);
?>
```

- **Is it a good idea to use the `module_invoke()` every time when I have to call `hook_block_view()` with different arguments?**
- **Is there any other function that can be used for calling the same function or any other function in the module after one- `module_invoke()`?**
- **Is there any other way of doing thing?**

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the same function over and over, that's true. But the parameters are different, so from a pure programming point of view, the processing could be completely different. I don't see another option to approach this.

- Is it a good idea to use the module_invoke() every time when I have to call hook_block_view() with different arguments?
  **Yes**
- Is there any other function that can be used for calling the same function or any other function in the module after one- module_invoke()? **Not that I'm aware of**
- Is there any other way of doing thing? **I don't think so**

More specifc, some functions allow passing an array of arguments instead of one. Eg node_load_multiple allows to pass 1 nid or whole list of nids. But hook_block_views doesn't allow this.

Comment: @Marten: Thank you for your time on this answer.
How good is the call for invoking a module every time(when it is already invoked)?
But leave the pure programming concepts, just basics. When I started using functions(procedures), it helped me to avoid the repeated lines of code with just a function call. And there should be a function for all such functionalities.
Now if this answer is correct, then Drupal really lacks it.